# how to run a program invisibly

Tags: windows

can i run a program on windows 7 so it doesn't appear in taskbar and system tray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called running it as a service I guess.

There are a number of offerings that allow you to do this:

- http://www.eltima.com/products/application-as-service/
- http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/
- http://www.firedaemon.com/

... none of them free, but a little more googling may find something free.

Comment: not exactly that i want but it will help.

Comment: i have found that type of free program as you mention. it is "srvman"